# iOS build failed in cordova branch metrics plugin

Tags: cordova-plugins, visual-studio-cordova, branch.io

I am getting below error on building Cordova-Ionic-PhoneGap-Deferred-Deep-Linking-SDK on iOS with cordova CLi 6.0.0 .

*** In file included from /Users/paarthdesai/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-*remote/builds/21837/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/Trestro/Plugins/io.branch.sdk/BranchSDK.m:8:
Trestro/Plugins/io.branch.sdk/BranchSDK.h:8:9: fatal error: 'Branch/Branch.h' file not found
 #import  ^
 1 error generated.****

Comment: This seems already fixed in the master branch. Check this Link: [iOS cordova build fails with error: Branch/Branch.h not found](https://github.com/BranchMetrics/Cordova-Ionic-PhoneGap-Deferred-Deep-Linking-SDK/issues/48).

Answer (score 0):

I updated the cordova version to CLi 6.1.1 After that I just made changed to my branchSDK.h file and build got succeeded. The issue was with visual studio tools for apache cordova. 
Please refer below github link for deails.

https://github.com/BranchMetrics/cordova-ionic-phonegap-branch-deep-linking/issues/139